# %TIME% as input parameter in batch file function

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch function to calculate the elapsed time. The function call works when I send in hard coded time strings e.g. `tdiff 23:38:27.23 01:26:39.43` but it gives error when passing variables that have time as shown below

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set startt=%time%
set /p s=Some process ...

call :tdiff startt, %time%
exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%

:tdiff
set startTime=%~1
set endTime=%~2

set "start=!startTime:%time:~8,1%=%%100)*100+1!"   
set "end=!endTime:%time:~8,1%=%%100)*100+1!"

set /A "elap=((((10!end:%time:~2,1%=%%100)*60+1!%%100)-((((10!start:%time:~2,1%=%%100)*60+1!%%100)"
if %elap% LEQ 0 set /A elap+=24*60*60*100

rem Convert elapsed time to HH:MM:SS:CC format:
set /A "cc=elap%%100+100,elap/=100,ss=elap%%60+100,elap/=60,mm=elap%%60+100,hh=elap/60+100"

echo Start Time: %startTime%
echo End Time: %endTime%
echo Elapsed Time: %hh:~1%%time:~2,1%%mm:~1%%time:~2,1%%ss:~1%%time:~8,1%%cc:~1%
exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

**Error**

```
Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).
0 was unexpected at this time.
```

Q2: Could I pass in `%~1` directly in the statement `set "start=!startTime:%time:~8,1%=%%100)*100+1!"` without having to resort to another variable `startTime`?

Comment: @jeb The syntax is correct. It is just a string substitution where the separator is substituted with the string "%100)*100+1"

Comment: But the result in `start` is simply `startt` not stuff like `17:14:08%100)*100+156` btw. the construct is more than ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers beginning with a zero are treated as octal and "08" and "09" are invalid octal numbers.
To avoid this, I prefix each part of the time with a "1" and calculate the modulus 100.

Btw. It's not possible to use the `%time%` directly with `CALL`, as in some formats the time uses `,` as separator (like `15:44:08,44`).
But the `,` is also a delimiter.

```
@echo off

set "t_start=%time%"
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
set "t_end=%time%"

call :calc_diff t_start t_end elapsed
echo %elapsed%
exit /b

:calc_diff
setlocal enabledelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%1 in ("!%1: =0!") DO (
    set /a "centiA=(((1%%1-100)*60+(1%%2-100))*60+(1%%3-100))*100+1%%4-100"
)

FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%1 in ("!%2: =0!") DO (
    set /a "centiB=(((1%%1-100)*60+(1%%2-100))*60+(1%%3-100))*100+1%%4-100"
)

(
    endlocal 
    set /a %3=%centiB% - %centiA%
    exit /b
)
```

Comment: Any ideas on Q2?

Comment: @ontherocks You don't need it at all. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: That was for extra information. I may need it for something else.

Comment: Try `set "start=!%~1:%time:~8,1%=%%100)*100+1!"`, the percent expansion is done first (1. `set start=!startt:,=%100)*100+1!`) and then the delayed expansion will be done

Comment: With this the output after substitution is wrong. For `set "start=!%~1:%time:~8,1%=ABCD!"` and time `20:27:41.15`, I would expect it to be `20:27:41ABCD15` but the output is `27:41.15:.=ABCD`

Comment: @ontherocks This happens when in `%1` is the time as string, but it should be a variable name, which contains the time